# Meaning of "have been brought into"

Tags: prepositions

Is the below sentence grammatically correct?

> The properties of this material have been brought into wide applications

What does "have been brought ***into***" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically correct, but it actually technically does not make sense as-is, because an "application" is not something that things would typically be "brought into".  It is close enough that we can probably guess the intended meaning, however:

To address your second question first, **have been brought into** is the **past perfect** **passive** form of **bring into** (past perfect: **bring** -> **have brought**; passive: **have brought** -> **have been brought**).  "to bring *(something)* into *(somewhere)*" can be used to talk about physically taking something to (inside) some location, or it is also often used metaphorically to talk about taking some concept and using it in some new context or area, for example:

> bring new computer modelling techniques into the field of biology

However, "bring into" can also be combined with (certain) nominalized verbs (a verb that has been turned into a noun form) to express the idea of causing some action to occur, for example:

> bring *(something)* into being *--> to cause something to exist*
>
> bring *(something)* into use *--> to cause something to be used*

Going back to your original sentence, I suspect the author was slightly mixing up the metaphorical "bring into" and the "causing to occur" sense, because in this case they both have somewhat similar feelings to them, but technically a more correct way to say it would have been:

> The properties of this material have been brought into **use in** wide applications.

Though "wide applications" is also almost certainly technically not what was meant either.  What the author presumably meant was actually:

> The properties of this material have been brought into **use in a wide variety of** applications.

Which then means that:

> *(unspecified people)* have caused the properties of this material to be used in many different kinds of applications.

Comment: I should clarify that the "bring into (nominalized verb)" construct does not work for all verbs.  There's really only a specific subset of verbs that this works with (generally only ones where the noun form used represents some persistent state)